# What was the minimum Jedi status required to have authority over Clone Troopers?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, attack-of-the-clones

Clearly not all of the Jedi had command over the Clone Troopers. What position did a Jedi have to attain within the Order to be able to command Clone Troopers?

Answer (score 8):

As we learn in [Star Wars: The Clone Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(film)), any Jedi who has attained the rank of Padawan can command Clone Troopers. That doesn't mean that they can countermand the orders of a more senior Jedi or a Jedi who is acting as a General in Command. Padawan Ahsoka discusses this situation with Commander Rex.

> "Thank you, but General Skywalker thinks they're fine where they are."
> "But they need cover."
> "They also need range."
> **"What if I gave you an
> order to move the cannons? You're a captain, and I'm a Jedi, so I
> technically outrank you, right?"
>
> "Technically, you're only a
> youngling."
>
> "Padawan!"**
> She looked as if she was going to continue, but
> she stopped of her own accord. Rex didn't need to interrupt her. It
> was as good a time as any to do what a fellow clone captain called
> picturizing, a lovely mild word for putting someone in their place.
> "Look, littl'un," Rex said, "why don't I explain how things are in the
> real world?"
> Ahsoka bristled visibly. Rex had never served with
> Togrutas before, so he wasn't sure what was normal for their
> youngsters. But he knew how a Jedi should behave, and she wasn't doing
> it.
> "I still think..."
> This time, he did interrupt.
> "Are you scared?"
> "No!"
> "Well, you should be. Because if you're not scared in a war,
> then you haven't grasped the severity of your situation."
> Rex sat down
> on a chunk of masonry so he was at eye level with her. He preferred
> training by example, but that would have involved letting her get
> blown up, and he had to cut her some slack. She was just a kid, full
> of a kid's weird mix of uncertainty and overconfidence about a
> brand-new rank, as if it would stop a blaster bolt if she brandished
> it enough.
> **"I take my orders from General Skywalker. It's called the
> chain of command, and it matters, because we all have to be clear
> who's in charge, or else we'll be running around like nuna. And you
> take your orders from him, too, because you're his Padawan.** With me so
> far?"
> That defiant jut of her chin had receded a little.
> "Yes, Captain."
> "Want to learn the most important things about being a soldier?
> I mean the things they don't teach you at the Temple."
> "How would you
> know what they teach Jedi?"
> "By watching you ..."
> "Okay."
> Ahsoka
> dropped her chin another fraction.
> "Experience matters."
> Rex
> ratcheted back a few notches. There was no point rubbing a kid's nose
> in it. You had to climb down with them.
> **"One," he said. "Orders. You
> follow orders. They keep you alive. Two, you're part of a team. We
> look out for our buddies. I cover your back, you cover mine. And three,
> an officer rank doesn't give you automatic respect. You earn it. It's
> not just Skywalker's rank that makes us give him one hundred percent.
> It's because he treats us with respect, and he puts himself on the
> line with us."**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Clone Wars - Official Movie Novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(novel))</sup></sub>

Warning: Mild Spoilers in this video beyond 00:15.

Comment: Okay, so a Youngling could not give orders to Clone Troopers, but a very young Padawan could?  That’s a hell of a lot of authority that the Galactic Republic gave to Padawans who had only a few years of training under their belts.

Comment: @FrankRodriguez - This is a Galaxy where a 12 year old girl can be the lead Senator of a planetary system of billions of people

Answer (score -1):

little late on this but Im going to say what u probably have already heard padawans can but only to a certain limit and if Ahsoka wasn't there Captain Rex would be Commander Rex if that helps and some padawans probably couldn't if their masters felt they couldn't and usually older jedi who are generals who can command troopers